# Create a Column that shows the day of the month based on a date column

Tags: database, pandas

I am attempting to return day of the week (i.e. Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, etc) based on a date column ("Posting_date"). I tried a for loop but got it wrong:

```
#First date of table was a Sunday (1 March 2019) => so counter starts at 6
posting_df3['Day'] = (posting_df3['Posting_date'] - dt.datetime(2019,3,31)).dt.days.astype('int16')

# Start counter on the right date (31 March 2019 is a Sunday)
count = 7

for x in posting_df3['Day']:
    if count != 7:
        count = 1
    else:
        count = count + 1
    posting_df3['Day'] = count
```

Not sure if there are other ways of doing this. Attached is an image of my database structure:

```
      level_0 Posting_date Reservation date  Book_window     ADR  Day
0           9   2019-03-31       2019-04-01           -1  156.00    0
1          25   2019-04-01       2019-04-01            0  152.15    1
2          11   2019-04-01       2019-04-01            0  149.40    1
3          42   2019-04-01       2019-04-01            0  141.33    1
4          45   2019-04-01       2019-04-01            0  159.36    1
...       ...          ...              ...          ...     ...  ...
4278      739   2020-02-21       2019-04-17          310  253.44  327
4279      739   2020-02-22       2019-04-17          310  253.44  328
4280       31   2020-03-11       2019-04-01          345  260.00  346
```

Final output should be 2019-03-31 Day column should return 7 since it is a Sunday
and 2019-04-01 Day column should return 1 since its Monday etc

Comment: What you need is `dt.weekday`. Look around for it. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.weekday.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
df['weekday']=pd.to_datetime(df['Posting_date']).dt.weekday+1
```

**Input**

```
level_0     Posting_date    Reservation_date    Book_window     ADR     Day
0   9          3/31/2019    4/1/2019                     -1     156.00  0
1   25          4/1/2019    4/1/2019                      0     152.15  1
2   11          4/1/2019    4/1/2019                      0     149.40  1
3   42          4/1/2019    4/1/2019                      0     141.33  1
4   45          4/1/2019    4/1/2019                      0     159.36  1
```

**Output**

```
level_0     Posting_date    Reservation_date    Book_window     ADR     Day     weekday
0   9         3/31/2019     4/1/2019                     -1     156.00  0       7
1   25         4/1/2019     4/1/2019                      0     152.15  1       1
2   11         4/1/2019     4/1/2019                      0     149.40  1       1
3   42         4/1/2019     4/1/2019                      0     141.33  1       1
4   45         4/1/2019     4/1/2019                      0     159.36  1       1
```